# Is it possible to find the button that was pressed for a specific command?

Tags: c#, xaml, icommand

If I have something like this:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}">Test</Button>
 <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}">another Test</Button>
```

TestCommand is a command object implementing ICommand.

Is it possible in the Execute function of TestCommand to detect which one of the two buttons was pressed?

I think this would be possible, if I use the object parameter, but I have other parameters to be passed, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

Try using CommandParameters:

```
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Param, ButtonUsed}">
       Test</Button>
```